# WP7 , Calculating Internet Speed

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, networking

I am building an application where URL sources will be decided by the speed of the internet connection(Bandwidth).
Is there a way that we can ascertain the speed of the internet connection ?

For Example : If the User of my application is using a low speed connection (2G) then i need to provide him with a suitable source.
If the user is using a 3G connection then i will provide him with a better quality content through another URL.

So for this i need to ascertain the speed of the internet connection that the user might have.
Kindly give me some guidance on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

send a data of some size to the user and get the total time it takes to finish sending the data. then calculate `data size / time needed`.

Comment: Bahamut : I donot want the server to determine the speed of the connection. I want the client to determine the speed of the connection and choose the source by itself.

Comment: same. you're gonna download the data and determine how much time it took and the calculation will be done on the client part.